# How to activate pose mode?

Tags: pose-mode

Downloaded a rigged model and want to move the bones. How do I enter the pose mode?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select the Armature in Object Mode and switch to Pose Mode by pressing  `Ctrl + Tab` [0]

[0] https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Bones